# Attach a JsonConverter to a single action in a controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, json.net

So I have a WebAPI controller with an action that takes an interface as a parameter, something like:

```
[HttpPost]
public IFoo RunBar(IBar parameters)
{
    //...
}
```

Now, of course, this doesn't run as-is because it doesn't know how to deserialize a `IBar` to a concrete class, so `parameters` is always `null`.

I have a converter to handle this, it's called `ConcreteTypeConverter<Bar,IBar>` and it'll basically just deserialize any `IBar` to the concrete class `Bar` and I can make this work if I register it globally with something like:

```
config.Formatters.JsonFormatter.SerializerSettings.Converters.Add(new ConcreteTypeConverter<Bar,IBar>())
```

But this is a) tedious and b) if I register a whole bunch of these, might it not have performance implications? So is there an easier way? Is there a way to attach a converter to an *action* to be used only for *this* particular action? Perhaps something conceptually equivalent to:

```
[JsonConverter(typeof(ConcreteTypeConverter<Bar, IBar >))]
[HttpPost]
public IFoo RunBar(IBar parameters)
{
   //...
}
```

Which obviously doesn't work because you can use `JsonConverterAttribute` on a method.

And if something like this doesn't already exist, where would you have to hook into the pipeline to intercept the call to an action and insert the converter before it attempts to deserialize the parameters?

Comment: Is there a strong reason for doing this? Seems like you're fighting against WebAPI here. Why not simply use the concrete class (which implements the interface anyway) as the action method's parameter, so the default binder can work its magic?

Answer (score 1):

So after poking around a while, I came up with this:

```
public class JsonConverterBindingAttribute : ParameterBindingAttribute
{
    public IEnumerable<JsonConverter> Converters { get; private set; }

    public JsonConverterBindingAttribute(params Type[] converters)
    {
        if (converters.Any(converter => !typeof(JsonConverter).IsAssignableFrom(converter)))
        {
            throw new ArgumentException($"a converter does not derive from JsonConverter");
        }
        Converters = converters.Select(converter => (JsonConverter)Activator.CreateInstance(converter));
    }

    public override HttpParameterBinding GetBinding(HttpParameterDescriptor parameter)
    {
        if (parameter == null)
            throw new ArgumentException("Invalid parameter");

        return new JsonConverterParameterBinding(parameter, Converters.ToArray());
    }
}

public class JsonConverterParameterBinding : HttpParameterBinding
{
    public JsonConverter[] Converters { get; private set; }

    public JsonConverterParameterBinding(HttpParameterDescriptor parameter, JsonConverter[] converter) : base(parameter)
    {
        Converters = converter;
    }

    public override Task ExecuteBindingAsync(ModelMetadataProvider metadataProvider, 
        HttpActionContext actionContext, 
        CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        var binding = actionContext
            .ActionDescriptor
            .ActionBinding;

        var type = binding
            .ParameterBindings[0]
            .Descriptor.ParameterType;

        var existingConverters = GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Formatters.JsonFormatter.SerializerSettings.Converters;

        return actionContext.Request.Content
            .ReadAsStringAsync()
            .ContinueWith(t =>
            {
                var str = t.Result;
                var obj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(str, type, existingConverters.Concat(Converters).ToArray());
                SetValue(actionContext, obj);
            });           
    }

    public override bool WillReadBody => true;
}
```

Which can be used like this:

```
[HttpPost]
public IFoo RunBar([JsonConverterBinding(typeof(ConcreteTypeConverter<Bar,IBar>)]IBar parameters)
{
   //...
}
```

Which works, but I'm not sure I'm 100% in love with this as a solution. A few notes:

I set it to accept multiple converters because if `IBar` contains a property that is, itself, also an interface (let's call it `IFar`), well, then you need to be able to provide a converter for that too! So you could do something like:

```
public IFoo RunBar([JsonConverterBinding(typeof(ConcreteTypeConverter<Bar,IBar>),
 typeof(ConcreteTypeConverter<Far, IFar>)]IBar parameters)
```

But that's also a bit unwieldy, so I thought it would be useful to be able to use any existing converters that you've already registered globally (because they are used in lots of places), hence why I concat the converters from `GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Formatters.JsonFormatter.SerializerSettings.Converters`, probably better would be to clone all the settings from there and just add the extra converters I need / want. Or maybe that just kinda defeats the whole point.

Also, there's probably some error checking that I ought to be doing, but as a first draft just to see if it *could* be done, it works in principle.